# JQuery UI Autocomplete: Response, Ctrl + A and Backspace

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-events, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm working on a form to add members to a project. Only members whose profiles are recorded in the system can be added. There are a name input field and a position select box. The position select box by default is disabled.

The idea:

- User types a name, autocomplete dropdown appears. The dropdown contains names of members whose profiles are recorded in the system.
- User picks a name in the dropdown, the position select box will undisabled.
- If after this, user makes any change to the name input field, the position select box is disabled again and the autocomplete dropdown appears again.

I put the disabled events into the response event of the autocomplete.

Problem: When I put <kbd>Backspace</kbd> to the input field, the position select box is disabled, but when I put <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> then <kbd>Backspace</kbd>, it isn't. How can I fix this?

```
$("#autocomplete").autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
        //some ajax stuffs
    }, 
    select: function (e, ui) {
        $('#verified').val('true'); //the name is already recorded 
        $('#selectPosition').removeAttr('disabled');
    },
    response: function(event, ui) {
        if($('#verified').val() == 'true') {
            $('#verified').val('');
            $('#selectPosition').attr('disabled','disabled');
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

The .change() method fires when there is a change in the input box. This change is detected **when the focus moves out of the input** box.
It works regardless of how the change was made - whether you use backspace to remove a character/characters, or you use Ctrl + A to select the entire text and remove it using backspace.
The event will fire when you move the focus out of the input box.

Comment: I added the following script to an HTML file containing an input box (needless to say, it should include JQuery):
`<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $('input').change(function() {
   console.log('Change!');
  });
 });
</script>`

Comment: It doesn't fire for me. I put Ctrl A then Backspace, nothing happened. Then I clicked on something else to move focus out of the input box, nothing happened either.

Comment: Let me take a look at your code; maybe you missed something.
I did exactly this and it worked for me.
Try using any other simple JQuery method to ensure your imports are working correctly.

Comment: It doesn't fire if input was empty, then you type something and then ctrl+a + backspace and click, :D.  That is stupid, but any other action that does change input text fires event normaly, even after ctrl+a backspace. :D. Strange question strang answer - try .blur(function(){}) instead :D.

Comment: I'm so sorry. I put the event in the response event of the autocomplete field, not the change event. And I meant to ask about the response event. I have edited the question.

Answer (score -1):

You could use .keyup() instead of .change() so it updates every time a key is released.

Comment: Can you update your question with the code you are using? Or better yet a JSFiddle.

Comment: I'm so sorry. I put the event in the response event of the autocomplete field, not the change event. And I meant to ask about the response event.  I have edited the question.